# Extremely slow Flex Remoting/Cffunction response when arguments include a string which can be cast to a VERY large number

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, remoting, scientific-notation

I've run into a strange problem that I've been wrestling with for a few days.  I'm hoping someone will have some insights.

I have a Flex app that uses standard remoting to access a SQL db via ColdFusion.  (Flex sdk 3.4 (yes, old), CF 10)

I've recently found a problem where if the arguments to a cffunction includes a string that *could be* a very large number ("2e4361251", for example), the remoting result/fault handler in my AS code will not get called for a VERY long time, effectively locking the app. (App logic requires that I wait for this operation to finish before moving on.)

My most recent test took **45 minutes** for the result handler to be called.

What the cffunction does does not matter.
If I am attempting to update my db, the update is successful (whether the string is used in that update or not), my app just doesn't get the result for a very long time;
If the cffunction does NOTHING, like
    
< cffunction name="myFunc" access="remote">
       < !-- do nothing -->
    < /cffunction>
it STILL takes an extremely long time to return.

Repeated testing has a noticeable effect on the server; CF starts eating up processor and RAM, though it will eventually recover.

Passing the string IN as a parameter is key; if I'm retrieving the string from the db, there is no problem.

These strings could represent VERY large numbers.  If I were trying to do any sort of calculations or other manipulations, I could maybe understand this.  But as I said, the function doesn't have to do anything at all, just the presence of the string causes the problem. (And I have verified that it is being passed as a String, not an int, Number, float, decimal, etc)

The string that alerted me to this issue originated with a user.  It is a catalogue number of some sort.  They had many with different letter/number combos; this one happened to use a single 'E'.  I cannot simply 'disallow' strings of this nature.

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and, more importantly at the moment, how I can avoid it?  A 45 min delay = 'frozen app' to the user.

Comment: Without specific, reproducible code samples, there is really nothing anyone will be able to do to help you.

Comment: What does a stack trace show of the CF thread?

Comment: I think you need to start by decoupling the situation. Is it Flex, or is it CF? Call the CF method directly. Call a stubbed endpoint which doesn't involve CF at all. Does that cast any light on where the issue lies? If so... re-pose the question accordingly.